# Customizing dark scrollbar using QGIS

Tags: qgis, gui, qgis-customization, theme

In QGIS 3, is there any way to make one small GUI customization, which is to make the scrollbar dark on a light background instead of light on a dark background in the Fusion theme?

For some reason I always grab the dark part, must be a habit from using other applications (e.g. Android Studio).  I'm not interested in "Night" mode alternatives, which are too extreme.  The "Windows" theme helps, I go for the scrollbar correctly, but it adds some clutter.  Tweaking the Fusion default theme would be ideal if there is a way to do it, maybe a config file somewhere.